# Virt-manager: How to ignore key sequence from host?

Tags: xfce, kvm, qemu, virt-manager

I'm on Debian+Xfce and I have two desktops. I set Super+F1 to take me to the first desktop and Super+F2 to take me to the second desktop.

I would like to run a virt-manager guest in full screen on the second desktop and still be able to switch back to the first desktop by pressing Super+F1. For that I need virt-manager to ignore or never receive the Super+F1 sequence.

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can hit `ctrl` + `alt` to get the mouse pointer out of VM and back to the host machine and then hit `Super` + `F1` to switch back to first desktop

Comment: Unfortunately Super+F1 is still sent to the VM. I wasn't me who downvoted you btw.

Comment: @anajoy666 strange, for me it works... :/

Comment: Tested again. It works if the mouse pointer is outside the VM view i.e. not in full screen.